# ConnectionResetError on a web-scrape run.

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am new to python.The below function gives the movie and director name from imdb. It works fine for a single link. But when i run it for a large list of links it gives **ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**.

What should i do? How to improve the code?

```
def get_director(movie_url):
    html=urllib.request.urlopen(movie_url).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    movie=soup.find("h1","header")
    movie_name=movie.find("span","itemprop").text
    d=soup.find("div","txt-block")
    director=d.find("span","itemprop").text
    return {'Movie':movie_name,'Director':director}
```

Comment: I don't know if it will work but you can try using the [time.sleep](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) method between calls to the `get_director` method. You might be hitting the server too quickly. Delaying the calls by even one second can help fix the problem.

Comment: I tried as you specified.Still getting the same error.

Comment: I still think it's a rate limiting issue of some sort. You should do as [Andrew Gorcester](http://stackoverflow.com/users/471671/andrew-gorcester) says and experiment with user agents and delays between requests.

Comment: Will a **try ...except** block work?If so where should I place it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds pretty likely that this is rate limiting or some other restriction on the server side and not a flaw in your code per se. You should start by seeing if the imdb has posted official rate or other restrictions on scraping; if they haven't, you have little choice but to experiment and back off until the errors stop.

Comment: You were right! It worked after a little trial and error.Anyway, my program took ~20 min to retrieve data from 250 links.How can i optimize the code ?

Comment: If that is due to rate limiting, then you cannot optimize your code except by learning what the rate limit is and adhering to that exactly, or by finding another way to get the data you want.